# How to specify test prerequisites in the ExtUtils::MakeMaker Makefile.PL

Tags: perl, perl-module, makemaker

`PREREQ_PM` specifies the runtime prerequisites, but how to specify which modules are required to run the test cases?

Should I use `BUILD_REQUIRES` for this?

Answer (score 4):

As of [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](http://www.metacpan.org/module/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker) 6.64, there is a `TEST_REQUIRES` parameter.

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.64;

WriteMakefile(
    ...,
    TEST_REQUIRES => {
        Test::More => 0.95,
        },
    ...,
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

The [CPAN::Meta::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aSpec) defines how modules communicate their prerequisites to the toolchain.  The version 2 spec revised [the way prerequisites are listed](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aSpec#PREREQUISITES).  The `test` phase now has its own list of prerequisites.

But MakeMaker hasn't been updated for the v2 spec, and likely never will be.  The only fully-compliant v2 distribution tool I know of is [Dist::Zilla](http://dzil.org/) (and I recommend it for more reasons than that).

When [CPAN::Meta::Converter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aConverter) converts from the v2 spec to [v1.4](http://module-build.sourceforge.net/META-spec-v1.4.html), it merges the `test` requirements into `build_requires`.

So yes, if you stick with MakeMaker, any modules that are required to run the tests should be listed in `BUILD_REQUIRES`.  `PREREQ_PM` should contain only modules that are still required *after* the module is installed.

Comment: Excellent explanation.  (And finally a good rationale for how I've been doing it all along. ;)

Comment: @smonff, this answer is out of date.  MakeMaker actually did get `TEST_REQUIRES` support just a few months after I wrote it.  I'll update it when I get a chance.

Comment: @cjm I appreciate you mention it :D !

Answer (score 1):

If the tests fail without a module, then I list it in `PREREQ_PM` regardless of whether it's needed for testing or for running the module.

If I need modules for some tests, but they are not needed to run the module, I detect those when the tests are run, and I skip the tests (with a PASS) if I can't find them.

I don't think there is any field in ExtUtils::MakeMaker for what you want.