# Is it possible to install perl prerequisites before distribution testing and how?

Tags: perl, testing, module, makefile, prerequisites

I try to *build* [a Perl distribution for a home-made module](https://metacpan.org/module/Dependencies::Searcher), from the [Module::Starter](https://metacpan.org/module/Module::Starter) base. Every test pass on my machine, but when I upload it to CPAN to get some more *universal* tests from cpantesters.org, [some test failed on other architectures or OS](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/D/Dependencies-Searcher.html), but I can't understand why. I can see in test reports that some of my prerequisites are not installed before testing but I would like it to.

I've tried to list these dependencies into the `Makefile.PL` `PREREQ_PM` hash and [then in the `TEST_REQUIRES` hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172364/how-to-specify-test-prerequisites-in-the-extutilsmakemaker-makefile-pl/12183364?noredirect=1#comment27801734_12183364), but it didn't changed a lot of results.

Then, when I've removed the dependencies from my local machine and tried to install my module using `Cpanm`, it downloads dependencies first, test passed and install has been a success.

This is my first try for a module, so I think I am missing something, maybe I am too used of the `Cpanm` magic. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've [seen this on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178522/how-to-run-build-installdeps-to-install-missing-prerequisites), it could be what I search : trigger a kind of `Build installdeps` from Makefile.PL

Comment: `Build` and `Makefile.PL` is somewhat contradicting... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is something different. Andreas' smoker very probably built the dependency `App::Ack` (which looks in the fail reports like being absent) successfully. But here come at least two problems:

- When a distribution gets tested, then its dependencies may or may not be installed already. However, it's guaranteed that all dependent modules are made available through the `PERL5LIB` environment variable, so `make test` usually works (To be more specific, if the `install Module` command is used in the CPAN shell, then all dependencies are installed immediately. If the `test Module` command is used, then dependencies are only built, but not installed. The CPAN user can do the installation later using `install_tested`). So it may be that `App::Ack` is not *installed* here, just *built*. Especially this means that the `ack` script is not installed in the final location.
- Even if it is installed, many smoke testers or users who have multiple perls installed in parallel use a non-standard directory for this perl. So `ack` wouldn't be installed in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, but in the bin directory belonging to this perl. This directory may or may not be in the user's `PATH` at all. So you cannot assume that `can_run("ack")` works here. A workaround here is to add `$Config{scriptdir}` temporarily to `$ENV{PATH}`. Another solution would be to use the App module instead of the script, if it's possible. Unfortunately it looks like `ack` can only be called as a script.

If you look at a [sample fail report](http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/93a26d4a-1f77-11e3-b2af-1cda7e66b2dc), then you can see that `App::Ack` was installed (it appears in the PREREQUISITES section both under requires and build_requires, you can also see which `App::Ack` version is installed in the "HAVE" column). You can also see the user's `PATH` (in the ENVIRONMENT section). And you may guess about the scriptdir for this perl, it's usually the same directory where the perl binary itself is installed, and the path to current perl is visible in `$^X` (under "Perl special variables").

If you want to reproduce the behavior, then you need to deinstall `ack` from your machine, build a custom perl using `./configure.gnu --prefix=/path/to/custom/perl-5.X.Y`, and use this perl for tests.

Comment: Hey @slaven-rezic, thanx for your detailed answer, I appreciate it. I will reconsider my testing plans. Thanx for taking the time to read the smoke reports and maybe some of my uggly code.